# Scanf() reads its own input and the input of the following scanf()

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm losing my mind with this error, and I can't understand what's wrong with it. I've done some debugging to make it work, but it doesn't go in the right way. For some reason the first `scanf()` reads two inputs, its own and the input of the following `scanf()`. By the way I'm using `%[^\n]s`, because in this way it should read strings with space. How can I fix everything?

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN_CODE 6
#define MAX_LEN_STRING 20

typedef struct{
    char course_code[MAX_LEN_CODE];
    char name[MAX_LEN_STRING];
    char trainer[MAX_LEN_STRING];
    int partecipants_max;
    int partecipants_num;
}t_course;

void main(){
    t_course new_course;

    system("clear");
    printf("Insert the code\n");
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", new_course.course_code);
    printf("Insert the name of the course\n");
    printf("> ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", new_course.name);
    printf("Insert the trainer\n");
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", new_course.trainer);
    do{
        printf("Insert the maximum number of partecipants (10-100)\n");
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%d", &new_course.partecipants_max);

        if(new_course.partecipants_max < 10 || 
        new_course.partecipants_max > 100)
            printf("ERROR: The number must be between 10 and 100!\n\n");

    }while(new_course.partecipants_max < 10 || 
        new_course.partecipants_max > 100);

    new_course.partecipants_num = 0;

    printf("\nCODE: %s\nNAME: %s\nTRAINER: %s\nPARTECIPANTS: %d\n", 
        new_course.course_code, new_course.name, 
        new_course.trainer, new_course.partecipants_max);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Insert the code
> aa3040
Insert the name of the course
> fitness and sport
Insert the trainer
> mario
Insert the maximum number of partecipants (10-100)
> 55

CODE: aa3040fitness and sport  // I CAN'T FIGURE OUT THIS STEP
NAME: fitness and sport
TRAINER: mario
PARTECIPANTS: 55
```

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Use `fgets` for user input, not `scanf`.

Comment: @melpomene Yes I know that fgets has protection for the overflow problem, but I'm obligated to use scanf in an exam. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @melpomene By the way, why should I use `int` and not `void` ?

Comment: Because that's what the C standard says. Basically the portable versions are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`; anything else is system specific (if your compiler documentation doesn't say `void main` is OK, it's probably not). See also http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html

Comment: Why do I keep seeing `void main() {}`? Has this ever been OK?

Comment: @AlexColucci-- understandable that you must use `scanf()` for an assignment. `scanf()` can also offer some overflow protection if you specify a maximum width with `%s`. But `scanf()` is tricky and error-prone, which is why you will see so many recommendations to avoid it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are overwriting the space for terminating null character**:

you have:

```
#define MAX_LEN_CODE 6
```

and in your `struct t_course`:

```
char course_code[MAX_LEN_CODE];
```

So the `course_code` can store 5 characters + 1 for terminating null character i.e, `'\0'`  to mark the end of the string, but you are overwriting space for terminating null character by providing 6 characters:

```
aa3040
```

Try providing +1 length:

```
//changing MAX_LEN_CODE value:
#define MAX_LEN_CODE 7

//or instead of changing MAX_LEN_CODE
//change the size of course_code in your struct:
char course_code[MAX_LEN_CODE + 1];
```

or instead make `scanf()` accept only 5 characters to avoid overwriting the terminating null character at the end by providing **width specifier**:

```
scanf("%5s", new_course.course_code);

//NOTE: You still need to consume the characters left in stdin
int consume; 
while((consume = getchar()) != '\n' && consume != EOF);
```

Answer (score 2):

`course_code` is an array of six `char`s, which is only sufficient to store a *NUL-terminated* string of five characters (since the `NUL` occupies a `char`). Since the code is actually six characters long, the `NUL` will be stored at `course_code+6`, which happens to be the first byte in `name`. So when you then read a string into `name`, the `NUL` is overwritten and you end up inadvertently concatenating the two strings.